# Printing an image in python

Tags: python, image, printing

I'm trying to print an image, literally to the python shell. This is only for the "see if it is possible" purposes, I'm not actually using this for anything, just a fun project of mine. Of course, I already know how to display images and have done a few projects in the past involving images, but I want to know if it is possible to actually print an image to the python shell.

For example, you get a shape that looks like a pyramid using these print statements:

```
print("        0        ")
print("       0 0       ")
print("      0 0 0      ")
print("     0 0 0 0     ")
print("    0 0 0 0 0    ")
print("   0 0 0 0 0 0   ")
print("  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ")
print(" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ")
print("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
```

and while this is obviously inefficient and needs for loops so that you don't have to write how 100 print statements, in case the image is pretty complicated, it could still be a method of showing an image. (Even though PIL and Pillow are WAY better in so many ways, this is obviously a really inefficient way to display an image).

I thought about certain ways to go about doing this. Obviously, we would need to get an input, so I'll have an image saved in my files (preferably a small one that isn't very detailed), and I'll get that image ready for use, something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_image(file_path):
    img = Image.open("path to image")
    return img

path = input("Please enter path to image: "):
img = get_image(path)
```

now we have the image ready to use. The problem comes when we need to print the image out to the shell, I was thinking about imaging modules that could kind of find all the pixels in the image to help me convert it. Something like this:

```
#import libraries that help with converting the image to "print" format

def convert(img):
    pass

def print_out(p_info):
    pass
```

and here, I'm assuming there's a library that can help with this. This idea is such a far away idea, and since it is only used for fun and entertainment, there's probably not going to be a python library that can do this. I'm open to any suggestions, so please let me know if you have any ideas.

UPDATE:

Resolved! I got plenty of great suggestions about the best python image packages to use.

Comment: Try using this library https://pypi.org/project/ascii-magic/

Comment: @Gaberocksall ascii-magic looks wonderful!  I'm a little disappointed that it relies so much on font coloring rather than the shapes of the characters themselves.  My introduction to ASCII art was text files meant to be printed on a Teletype, and I believe they were done by hand.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/TheZoraiz/ascii-image-converter, it is colourless, so it should be fine for your use case @MarkRansom

Comment: These all work great! Thanks for all the great answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do better than that with `imgcat`. I believe it was originally developed by/for iTerm2, but it now works on many Terminal types. You can read about it and download it [here](https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html), or call it from Python using the [imgcat](https://pypi.org/project/imgcat/) Python package.

It doesn't work in the standard macOS Terminal, but it does work in iTerm2, and in `tmux` sessions. More fun than that though, it works inside the iPad/iPhone `blink` app, so I screen-grabbed it in action when ssh-ed into my Mac Studio from my iPad:

[image]

Photo by [Mahbod Akhzami](https://unsplash.com/@mahbodakhzami?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/multi-colored-pencils-on-black-surface-59OukP9BTTU?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash)

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer! I did try using it though-and I'm running into an error. When I try it, it just displays an empty line, no image. I've checked the docs, but no help there. What do you think is going on?

Comment: I'd have to guess you are not using a compatible Terminal program.

Comment: I'm using windows powershell...is that supported?